# Unity GPS location on Android infrequently updating

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-gps

In a unity app, I start the location service

```
Input.location.Start(0,0); //tried various other values and default
```

and then continuously poll it like

```
Input.location.lastData
```

and check the timestamp against the timestamp of the last location to see changes.
Unity automatically requests the fine location access and the manifest seems fine.

The problem is that the location is very infrequently updated. Can be as much as multiple kilometers movement and minutes of time between new locations.
If i then start google maps navigation, which uses the gps as well, my application will get new gps locations very frequently, as expected.

It seems that somehow Unity is not really turning on gps, but apart from starting, polling and having the proper manifest, I fail to see what else I can do.

This minimal example shows the slow update. An application with just a ui text and this behavior running will show that gps location is rarely updated, unless some other app, such as google maps navigation, uses the gps.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text Info;
    void Start()
    {
        Input.location.Start(0.1f, 0.1f);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Info.text = 
            Input.location.status.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine +
            Input.location.lastData.timestamp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, found the solution, which is silly: turn off "improving" location with wifi.

Under settings/locationaccess at the bottom under google location accuracy, turn OFF "make location more accurate using wifi".

While I asked for accurate location with updates after even the smallest movement, apparently this more accurate location, suplementing with wifi, is causing it to not update.

That is rather backwards, since what it apparently means is that it will *only* use wifi when you allow it to improve location with wifi, and not as expected use gps *and* wifi.

When this is turned off, I get frequent updates, as expected.

If this is an issue with unity or with android, that is unclear, but it is certainly a problem, albeit a fixable one, as long as you know about it.